# Module not found: Can't resolve './pages' Failed to compile

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am importing a home component stored in pages folder. Adding it to the Router of my application

Get the error below
./src/App.js Module not found: Can't resolve './pages'

But I seem to have done it correctly?Module not found: Can't resolve './pages'

Please help me why its saying module not found when its there

App.JS CODE

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from "./pages";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/browse">
          <p>I will be the sign in page</p>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/signin">
          <p>I will be the sign up page</p>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/browse">
          <p>I will be the browse page</p>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

home.js CODE

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <h1>Hello Sambulo</h1>      
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you share your project folder structure?

Answer (score 1):

When you import from `'./pages'` the default behavior is to look for for a file named `index.js` in the `./pages` folder.

If you want to import `home.js` you have to change the import to

```
import Home from "./pages/home.js";
```

the `.js` at the end is optional as `.js` is the default file extension for imports

Comment: can you show us your project directory by taking a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

According to React component name convention, it is better to use Home.js as the file name.
So this one is also working.

```
import Home from "./pages/Home";
```

Component name should be in PascalCase.

For example, MyComponent, MyChildComponent etc.